# Восстановление секрета схемы Блэкли. Решение СЛАУ по модулю

Tags: алгоритм, криптография

Здравствуйте, реализовываю схему разделения секрета Блэкли. С генерацией секрета, а затем точки для него, а также разделения, естественно, проблем нету.
А вот с восстановлением секрета есть : для этого надо решить СЛАУ(найти пересечение плоскостей), но вся проблема состоит в том, что там все вычисления производятся по модулю(простому) и, если решать СЛАУ стандартными методами(например методом Гаусса), ответом выдается дробное решение(т.к. модуль не учитывается), и следовательно получить начальный секрет таким образом не получиться(изначально только целочисленные координаты).
Единственный вариант, приходящий на ум - перебрать все варианты из поля модулей, и отыскать нужный нам единственный целочисленный ответ, но количество всех правильных решений в таком случае будет Р в К-ой степени(Р-модуль, К-количество неизвестных).
Не могли вы подсказать, как реализовать данную схему правильно.

Comment: Вы решаете систему в поле? Там есть обратные элементы, и они не дробные.

Comment: Вот именно этот вопрос меня и интересует : как решать СЛАУ в поле. На предварительных этапах можно обойтись без этого - просто пару раз посчитать по модулю.
А вот для решения уравнений потребуется другой метод, нежели стандартные. Вот я и хотел бы узнать как это сделать.

Comment: Так в чём проблема? Метод Гаусса катит. Просто вместо деления действительных чисел вам нужно деление в поле.

Comment: Благодарю. Что-то я подзабыл про деление в поле)